# Why was Zormpa changed to Zorba?

Tags: transliteration

In the original Greek text, Alexis Zorba's surname was Ζορμπά [Zormpa]. Does anyone know why the name came to be transliterated, in the English translation, as Zorba?

Comment: The letter beta in Ancient Greek was pronounced like the sound /b/. In New Greek, it is pronounced like the sound /v/. Whenever they want to render the sound /b/ in New Greek, they write μπ. So μπ is more or less pronounced like /b/ in New Greek.

Comment: Or to put it more bluntly: his name is transliterated _Zorba_ because it is **pronounced** [zor'ba] in Greek. Similarly, the music style is called [rebetika](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebetiko) because that's how it's pronounced in Greek, spelt ρεμπέτικα. I'd say this question is off-topic because it's really more about Greek than English.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Greek rather than English

Comment: (@Cerberus and Janus Bahs Jacquet) Would the people posting answers in the comments please refrain from doing so. If you have an answer, please use the "Your Answer" box.

Comment: I'm not sure that this *is* off topic. I'll let the community decide, but if something is used a certain way in English, that would seem on topic to me. c.f. pronunciation of the names of famous people.

Comment: @MattЭллен this has nothing to do with English, but with pronunciation of _Greek_ and transliteration of Greek into the Latin alphabet. That English happens to use that alphabet does not make it a question about English. This is just about as on-topic as a question about the Dutch pronunciation of the _ui_ diphthong.

Comment: @oerkelens it's about transliteration into English. The fact the English uses a Latin-esque alphabet is conincidental.

Comment: @MattЭллен - There is very little specifically English about the transliteration. Even a Greek would transliterate it the same way when writing Greek in Latin script.

Comment: By the way - the guy's name in Greek is Ζορμπάς. The version without the final sigma is the accusative/vocative.

Comment: @MattЭллен I agree with what oerkelens has said, which is exactly why I posted a comment, not an answer. I do not believe answers should be given on off-topic questions at all. The transliteration of _Ζορμπάς_ to _Zorba(s)_ is not English: it is cross-linguistic. The same transliteration (originating in Greece) is used in a wide variety of languages. _Sorbas_ would be a specifically German transliteration and I might **just** consider that on-topic for a German SE, but _Zorba(s)_ is not specifically English, and not on-topic for ELU in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Because 'μπ' is pronounced /b/ (or /mb/ after vowels) in Modern Greek. It is the only way of writing /b/, since 'β' is pronounced /v/.

Compare 'μπύρα' = 'beer'.